# Removing the special price in bulk in Magento 1.6

Tags: php, sql, magento

I have a heavy list of products that have a special price until the end of March, unfortunately, as I wasn't told how long the discount will last, I never set an end date.

I'm not overly proficient in **SQL** or **PHP**, so I wouldn't know how to approach **SQL** query that would set the *end date* to *March 31st* or simply remove all special prices.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a specific software product, not primarily about programming. If you stated the table layout and gave some sample data, somebody might help you anyways, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that from the backend. Just go to `Catalog->Products` check the checkbox near each product you with a special price and select from the top right corner the action 'Update attributes'. You will see a screen with all the attributes that can be changed. Set 31st of March as the 'Special price to date' and save.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even know about that option, I found a bunch of other useful things to do with bulk attribute updating as well. Worked like a charm.